# What is this block and wall type?

Tags: terraria

When I was surfing the Terraria wiki I came across this:

[image: Picture of backwall in question]

It is an animation of a character in molten armour using a Flower of Fire.

But what is the name of the blocks and the background walls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they are [Stone Slabs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stone_Slab).  It's easy to craft from stone, but you need the [right bench](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heavy_Work_Bench) to make it.